# Why Qt5 status is not visible for CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5

In my "Summary" in CMake the lines

```
  caffe_status("  Qt5Widgets        :" Qt5Widgets_FOUND THEN "${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES} (${Qt5Widgets_VERSION})" ELSE "No")
  caffe_status("  Doxygen           :" DOXYGEN_FOUND THEN "${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} (${DOXYGEN_VERSION})" ELSE "No")
```

results in lines

```
--   Qt5Widgets        :   No
--   Doxygen           :   /usr/bin/doxygen (1.8.11)
```

My app is built, and uses Qt5 widgets. What could be the reason why the status is not visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package), the variable would be called `Qt5_FOUND`. If you want `Qt5Widgets` component to be optional, use two `find_package` calls - one for `REQUIRED` components and second for `Qt5Widgets` one.